# mongoDB 3.4.7 error The field 'w' is not a valid collection option

Tags: mongodb, database

i am trying to create a new collection in mongodb  giving write acknowledgment permission

i tried doing it this way

```
db.createCollection(databaseName, { w: 1 });
```

but it gives me  errors saying

```
MongoError: The field 'w' is not a valid collection option. Options: { w: 1 }
at Function.MongoError.create (C:\monex\example\main\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:31:11)
at C:\monex\example\main\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:778:66
at Callbacks.emit (C:\monex\example\main\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:95:3)
at .messageHandler (C:\monex\example\main\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:249:23)
at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\monex\example\main\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:265:22)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:172:18)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:130:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:535:20)
```

Comment: Do you understand the basic concept that simply writing "any data" to a MongoDB collection or database namespace creates it? This is not an RDBMS, You don't need to define each database or collection in order to use it. ["Write Concern"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/) is a concept of "connections" or "operations" and is not created for the collections themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.createCollection("log", { capped : true, size : 5242880, max : 5000 } )
```

try this and it creates collection

```
db.createCollection("log1", { w: 1} );
```

This also creates the collection

and also check the MongoDB version